# Security with "web_accessible_resources"

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources#Using_web_accessible_resources) state:

```
To enable a web page to contain an <img> element whose src attribute points to this image,
you could specify "web_accessible_resources" like this:

"web_accessible_resources": ["images/my-image.png"]

The file will then be available using a URL like:

moz-extension://<extension-UUID>/images/my-image.png"

<extension-UUID> is not your extension's ID.
It is randomly generated for every browser instance.
This prevents websites from fingerprinting a browser by examining
the extensions it has installed.
```

So, I would think that these resources cannot be read by any web page outside the extension, since they would need to know the random UUID.

However, the same [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources#Security) also state:

```
Note that if you make a page web-accessible, then any website may then link or redirect
to that page. The page should then treat any input (POST data, for examples)
as if it came from an untrusted source, just as a normal web page should.
```

I don't understand how "any website may then link or redirect to that page". Wouldn't it need to know the random UUID? How else could a webpage access this resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of Web Accessible Resources is to be able to include them in a web context.

While you can communicate the random UUID to the webpage so that it can use the file, it doesn't have to be included by the website code itself. Here's a hypothetical scenario:

> You're writing an extension that adds a button to `evil.com` site's UI. That button is supposed to have an image on it.
>
> You bundle the image with your extension, but to add it as `src` or CSS property to the webpage you need to be able to reference it from a web context.
>
> So, you make it web-accessible, and then inject your UI element with a content script.

Perfectly plausible scenario.

Note that a random third-party site `villains-united.com` can't just scrape the URL to know if your extension is installed, since the URL is per-browser unique. This is the intent behind WebExtensions's UUID over Chrome's extension-id model.

However, let's continue our hypothetical scenario, from a security perspective.

> The operators of `evil.com` are unhappy with your extra UI. They add a script to their code that looks for added buttons.
>
> That script can see the DOM properties of the button, including the address of the image. **Now** `evil.com`'s code can see your UUID.
>
> Being the good guy, your extension's source code is available somewhere, including the page that launches nuclear missiles if called (why you would have that and why it would be web-accessible is another matter, perhaps to provide the functionality to `good-guys-last-resort.org`).
>
> `evil.com`'s script now can reconstruct the URL of this trigger page and XHR it, plunging the planet into nuclear apocalypse. Oops. You probably should've checked the origin of that request.

Basically, if a web-accessible resource is *used* in a page, the UUID likely leaks to that page's context via DOM. That may not be a page you control.

Comment: OK, but since the UUID is randomly generated for every browser instance, how would a website know that this change to the DOM was made by a specific extension?

Comment: Strictly speaking: it wouldn't. But the point of the above _fable_ is to illustrate that the UUID can leak, and the site's evil code can _try_ probing exposed resources, hence page loads from the web context should not assume who called them and have checks in place to mitigate security issues. Basically, it's a _risk_ to be aware of; may not be problematic for _most_ users of `web_accessible_resources`, but worth _thinking_ about.